# Restore from backup to another instance

Tags: aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-opendistro

I was able to take backup of elastic server data using the steps mentioned in this thread...

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=930345#930345

But I am not able to restore data to another server. I tried a similar command line...

```
curl -XPOST 'http://search-weblogs-abcdefghijklmnojiu.us-east-1.a9.com/_snapshot/weblogs-index-backups/snapshot_1/_restore'
```

But I get connection refused error.
How do I restore snapshot backup of one server to another es instance?

Comment: a lot of steps, so which is you exactly did?

Comment: wich version of elastic are you using?

Comment: Can you connect to the ES instance at all? Does your Security Group and NACL allow connections to the ES instance from your IP?

Comment: 7.4 (latest) version offered by elasticsearch service of AWS @Claudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 steps to complete that task.

```
1) Create IAM role
2) Use the boto script to create snapshot repo
3) Use Kibana to take the snapshot
```

As explained here...

http://oksoft.blogspot.com/2020/03/snapshot-and-restore-elastic-data-to-s3.html